# find oldest createdate and keyid from list of dicts and return result in a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, datetime

I get below response from a system:

```
{'KeyMetadata':
[
    {
        'UserName': 'thisusernameA',
        'KeyId': 'ABCDE12345',
        'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022,11, 30, 13, 7, 43, tzinfo=tzutc())
    },
    {
        'UserName': 'thisusernameA',
        'KeyId': 'CDEFG678911',
        'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022,12, 9, 14, 50, 36, tzinfo=tzutc())
    }
]
}
```

so the user has two different keys, with a different createdate.
I have to isolate the KeyId and CreateDate from the oldest key, and return the result in a dict like this:

```
{'KeyId': 'ABCDE12345', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022,11, 30, 13, 7, 43, tzinfo=tzutc())}
```

I seems that I have figured out a way to at least get the oldest date:

```
mylist=my_result["KeyMetadata"]
seq = [x['CreateDate'] for x in mylist]
my_oldest=min(seq)
```

But what do I do next? how do I get the relating KeyId and construct a dict response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't separate the data, use `min` with a custom key to use the date

```
data = {'KeyMetadata': [
    {'UserName': 'thisusernameA', 'KeyId': 'ABCDE12345',
     'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 13, 7, 43, tzinfo=tzutc())},
    {'UserName': 'thisusernameA', 'KeyId': 'CDEFG678911',
     'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 9, 14, 50, 36, tzinfo=tzutc())}
]}

min_item = min(data['KeyMetadata'], key=lambda item: item['CreateDate'])
print(min_item)
# {'UserName': 'thisusernameA', 'KeyId': 'ABCDE12345', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 13, 7, 43, tzinfo=tzutc())}
```